# node.js example program for bluemix's speech to text gives 403 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

I was trying out the example node.js program for bluemix's speech to text.I added in the username and password for the api credential but when i ran the program on node.js, I was given a `Error: Server responded with a non-101 status:403`. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Here is the example code

```
'use strict';

var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var fs = require('fs');

var speech_to_text = watson.speech_to_text({
  username: '{username}',
  password: '{password}',
  version: 'v1',
  url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text-beta/api'
});

var params = {
  content_type: 'audio/wav',
};

// create the stream
 var recognizeStream = speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream(params);

// // pipe in some audio
fs.createReadStream(__dirname +    '/resources/speech.wav').pipe(recognizeStream);

// // and pipe out the transcription
recognizeStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('transcription.txt'));


// listen for 'data' events for just the final text
// listen for 'results' events to get the raw JSON with interim results, timings, etc.

recognizeStream.setEncoding('utf8'); // to get strings instead of Buffers from `data` events

['data', 'results', 'error', 'connection-close'].forEach(function(eventName) {
 recognizeStream.on(eventName, console.log.bind(console, eventName + ' event: '));
 });
```

Thanks

*apology for not attaching the sample code ealier

Comment: please show the code, what you r trying

Comment: It's hard to say without any code sample

Answer (score 2):

The **service url** is wrong.

Instead of:

```
https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text-beta/api
```

use:

```
https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api
```

or leave it out. For example:

```
var speech_to_text = watson.speech_to_text({
  username: '{username}',
  password: '{password}',
  version: 'v1'
});
```

Comment: i am using a beta account though, that is the service url provided by the credential manager. In any case, I have tried both and the problem still persist. Thanks for your help though

Comment: The beta service is not longer available. Try to create a new service instance and go from there